# x86 assembly multiply two 32 bit numbers

Tags: assembly, att

I am learning intel assembly language(att syntax) in my free time and I was just wondering how you can multiply two numbers lets say 5 and 2 together without using the mul command?

Comment: Since you have a multiple of 2 there, you can use shift left, shift right to multiple / divide by 2 or a multiple of 2.

Comment: Hi Jack, if you want answers in ASM, consider using the [assembly tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) rather than the [c tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)...

Comment: You could also use `imul`. Or `aad`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your CPU is defective somehow, you would just *use* the `mul` command :-)

However, in a general sense, you just need to be aware that multiplication is repeated addition, so `4 x 7` is seven lots of four added together: `4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4`.

So the simple psuedo-code for such a beast would be:

```
def mul(unsigned a, unsigned b):  # line 1
    res = 0                       # line 2
    while b > 0:                  # line 3
        res = res + a             # line 4
        b = b - 1                 # line 5
    return res                    # line 6
```

Using your test data in a sample dry run shows how this works:

```
Line#   a    b   res
-----  ---  ---  ---
    1    5    2    ?
    2              0
    3                 (b>0, keep going)
    4              5
    5         1
    3                 (b>0, keep going)
    4             10
    5         0
    3                 (b==0, exit loop)
    6                 (returns 10)
```

Note that that's using unsigned values only, you can handle signed values with just a slight modification:

```
def mul(int a, int b):
    sign = 1
    if a < 0:
        a = -a
        sign = -sign
    if b < 0:
        b = -b
        sign = -sign

    res = 0
    while a > 0:
        res = res + b
        a = a - 1

    if sign == -1:
        res = -res
    return res
```

Also keep in mind that there are actually more *efficient* ways of doing multiplication that involve bit shifting of the values (minimising the additions needed) rather than simplistic repeated addition.

By that I mean a calculation like `9999 x 9999` will have about 10,000 additions performed using the simple method. By using shifts, you can limit the additions needed to nine per digit in one of the numbers and just under one per digit for the other number, meaning you can get away with about 40 additions for that calculation above.

This will hopefully make sense when you realise that you can simplify `9999 x 9999` down to:

```
     9999 x 9 -> nine additions
+   99990 x 9 -> nine additions
+  999900 x 9 -> nine additions
+ 9999000 x 9 -> nine additions
                 \____________/
                       |
                       V
                 three additions
```

If you want to see how shifting works in more detail, Wikipedia has an [article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add).

---

As an aside, you can get quite good performance when multiplying by a constant since you know in advance what operations need to be carried out. For example, multiplying a register by ten could be done with something like (keeping in mind my assembly days are long in the past):

```
mul_ax_by_10: push bx      ; save registers
              shl  ax      ; ax <- orig_ax * 2
              push ax      ; save for later add
              shl  ax
              shl  ax      ; ax <- orig_ax * 8
              pop  bx      ; bx <- orig_ax * 2
              add ax, bx   ; ax <- (orig_ax * 8) + (orig_ax * 2)
                           ;    <- orig_ax * (8 + 2)
                           ;    <- orig_ax * 10
              pop  bx      ; restore saved register
              ret          ; result in ax
```

Comment: yea, I know how to write it out in c code but I do not know how to do it in assembly.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to multiply two numbers using the shift commands. Let say we stored 5 in a and 10 in b when we shift will the 5 and 10 be in the binary representation.

Comment: On x86, where you have the magical `LEA` instruction, multiplying `EAX` by a constant 10 is as simple as: `leal (,%eax,4), %edx` + `addl %edx, %eax` + `addl %eax, %eax`. Of course, this clobbers the `EDX` register, so if you wanted to save that, you could do the pushes and pops.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with [c](/questions/tagged/c), I assume you're struggling with GCC's inline assembler.

In the good old decimal days you did a multiplication - e.g. 11 * 14 - as follows:

1. You took the rightmost digit of the multiplier (11) = 1,  and multiplied it with the multiplicand (14) = 14
2. You took the next digit left of the multiplier = 1, multiplied it by the multiplicand = 14 and shifted the result decimal left by one digit = 140. You can also shift the multiplicand instead of the result: 1 * 140 = 140.
3. You added the results to the final result: 14 + 140 = 154.

This algorithm is also valid in the brave new world of binarism:

1. Take the rightmost **bit** of the multiplier (1011b) by shifting the multiplier to the right = 1. "Multiply" it by the multiplicand (1110b). This is not really a multiplication. You've got only two  options: 0 * 1110b = 0 and 1 * 1110b = 1110b. The result is according to the bit 0 or the multiplicand. Add it to the final result.
2. If the multiplier is greater than null then the next bit waits as rightmost bit in the multiplier. Shift the multiplicand to the left by one bit (the second option in step 2. above) and goto step 1.

The GCC program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned mul (unsigned multiplier, unsigned multiplicand)
{
    unsigned r = 0;
    while (multiplier)
    {
        if (multiplier & 1) r += multiplicand;
        multiplier >>= 1;
        multiplicand <<= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

unsigned mul_asm (unsigned multiplier, unsigned multiplicand)
{
    unsigned result = 0;

    asm
    (
        "movl %[multiplier], %%edx;"        // EDX = multiplier
        "movl %[multiplicand], %%ecx;"      // ECX = multiplicand
        "xorl %%eax, %%eax;"                // Result = 0

        "L1:;"                              // While-loop
        "shrl $1, %%edx;"                   // Get rightmost bit of the multiplier
        "jnc 1f;"                           // Skip the next line if this bit == 0
        "leal (%%ecx,%%eax), %%eax;"        // Add multiplicand to result (without changing flags)
        "1:;"                               // Local jump label
        "leal (,%%ecx,2), %%ecx;"           // Shift multiplicand left by one bit (without changing flags)
        "jnz L1;"                           // While EDX != 0 (zero flag from the shrl-line)

        "movl %%eax, %[result];"            // Return value

        : [result] "=m" (result)            // Output
        : [multiplier] "m" (multiplier),    // Input
          [multiplicand] "m" (multiplicand)
        : "%eax", "%ecx", "%edx", "cc"      // Clobbered registers & flags
    );

    return result;
}

int main ( void )
{
    unsigned result, multiplier, multiplicand;

    multiplier = 17;
    multiplicand = 23;

    result = multiplier * multiplicand;
    printf ("direct:  %u * %u = %u\n", multiplier, multiplicand, result);

    result = mul (multiplier,multiplicand);
    printf ("mul:     %u * %u = %u\n", multiplier, multiplicand, result);

    result = mul_asm (multiplier,multiplicand);
    printf ("mul_asm: %u * %u = %u\n", multiplier, multiplicand, result);

    return 0;
}
```